# How to Auto generate Hibernate POJO from MySQL in Eclipse without creating new Hibernate project?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to to use the hibernate reverse engineering by generating the `POJO` from the database ,after searing I found a tool called `Hibernate tools` to generate but when I need to generate `POJO` I have to create a `Hibernate project` ??? it won't allow me to create a `hibernate` `pojo`in my `JavaFX` project ?? is there an alternative tools for eclipse to create hibernate entity in any project ?

Comment: Try enabling JPA in your Project Facet property, and configure its connection there itself. Then right click your project, and under JPA Tools select generate entities from table. This should do it

Comment: how to enable the JPA in my project ?

Comment: Select your project, then go to Project>>properties>>Project Facet

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Hibernate Perspective in Eclipse,Go to Hibernate Code Generation configuration. You can select your cfg and select the output directory and package where you want your pojos and hbm to be generated.

Comment: what do you mean by `Hibernate Perspective ` how to find it in eclipse ?

Comment: Window>>Open Perspective>>Other(Select Hibernate after clicking on other)

Answer (score 0):

You might have already gone through how to generate POJO and .hbm.xml files using hibernate eclipse plugin if not follow this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/), To answer why you need project is because it allows you to configure the datatype mapping which is auto generated and allows you to also generate specific set of table by specifying them in `hibernate.cfg.xml` , Also Hibernate perspective doesn't come by default in eclipse, you need to download it from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=1617241